# how to allow figures to float inside paragraph?

Tags: floats

I have a problem with floating figures... It seems like latex does not allow the figures to float inside a paragraph, but only in between them. This results in a big waste of space, espacially with large figures and long paragraphes.

I'm using the article class with twocolumn. And also I'm using lyx, but if you can explain the issue in latex i will be able to translate it into lyx.

Thank You!

Comment: What do you mean with 'float inside paragraph'? Are you looking for [`wrapfig`](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/wrapfig), [`picins`](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/picins) or [`floatflt`](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/flotflt)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not asking for `wrapfig` as @Ignasi suspect, use the package `float`(add to the preamble `\usepackage{float}`) and the `H` option in the figure (`\begin{figure}[H]`), but personally I consider a better design left the floats at the top or bottom of the pages(`t` or `b` options). It take less space too.